# C# Read Write TextFile End In The Middle

Tags: c#, task, file-handling

I run a Method, there're three part, part 1 and 3 are all the same to "read text file",

and part2 is to save string to text file,

```
// The Save Path is the text file's Path, used to read and save
// Encode can use Encoding.Default
public static async void SaveTextFile(string StrToSave, string SavePath, Encoding ENCODE)
{
    // Part1  
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(SavePath, ENCODE))
        {
            string result = "";
            while (sr.EndOfStream != true)
                result = result + sr.ReadLine() + "\n";

            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    // Part2
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(SavePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, ENCODE))
            {
                await sw.WriteAsync(StrToSave);
                await sw.FlushAsync();
                sw.Close();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Save");
            fs.Close();
        }
    }

    // The Run End Here And didn't Continue to Part 3

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    // Part3
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(SavePath, ENCODE))
        {
            string result = "";
            while (sr.EndOfStream != true)
                result = result + sr.ReadLine() + "\n";

            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

But I find it strange that the process end at the place where Part2 complete, and the process directly end but didn't continue on Part3,

What's the reason to this condition? Generally the process should go through whole method but should not stop in the middle

(one more question)
And is there some other way can do the purpose of part2, and also can continue to part3 to comlplete whole method?

Comment: Was there an exception?

Comment: Is this code inside a try/catch block? Probably you got an exception in the middle of it.

Comment: no,  even I place the three using block seperately in three try catch, the process still end at part2 and under debugging I didn't see it go into the catch block

Comment: Stepping through the code in the debugger should show you the issue. What does it tell you?

Comment: I didn't see any message and it smoothly end at part2, no error, but i just find in the output window the last message is"The thread 0x2ba8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x2704 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[7256] test20151104 Console.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[7256] test20151104 Console.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0)."   but it seems meaningless to me

Comment: From MSDN: An [`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) expression does not block the thread on which it is executing. Instead, it causes the compiler to sign up the rest of the async method as a continuation on the awaited task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are telling your app to `await` the methods, but never getting the Task result or a giving it a chance to complete. From what you've shown so far, you don't need the async stuff anyway, and **greatly** simplify the code:

```
public static void SaveTextFile(string StrToSave, string SavePath, Encoding ENCODE)
{
    //Part1  
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(File.ReadAllText(SavePath, ENCODE));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    //Part2
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText(SavePath, StrToSave, ENCODE);
        MessageBox.Show("Save");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    //Part3
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(File.ReadAllText(SavePath, ENCODE));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I have not spend more time on searching more method about readwritetext yet, this seems a better way

Answer (score 2):

It could be because you are writing an async void method and you are calling some async methods in part 2. Try to change the async methods in part 2 to non-async methods:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, ENCODE))
{
    sw.Write(StrToSave);
    sw.Flush(); // Non-async
    sw.Close(); // Non-async
}
```

Does it behave as you expect now?